# shellscript reading variables from a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I am working on a project where the requirement is like one script file will set the variables and another script file has to get those variables and manipulate it. I am storing the variables from first script into a file and in second script file I am reading it.

In first script file, first.sh , I am doing like

```
echo "a=6" > test.dat
echo "b=7" >> test.dat
echo "c=8" >> test.dat
```

I use `>` for the first variable where it overwrites and for the next values it appends. So the file will have the latest values always.

Is there any better approach than this ?

In the second script file how can read and fill the appropriate values ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load this variables from the script using `source`:

```
source test.dat
```

or just

```
. test.dat
```

Example:

```
$ echo "a=6" > test.dat ; echo "b=7" >> test.dat ; echo "c=8" >> test.dat
$ cat test.dat 
a=6
b=7
c=8
$ . test.dat
$ echo $a $b $c
6 7 8
```

If you have a script/program that generates these variables, you can also use `eval`.

Example:

```
$ cat generate.sh
echo a=6
echo b=7
echo c=8

$ bash generate.sh 
a=6
b=7
c=8

$ eval $(bash generate.sh)
$ echo $a $b $c
6 7 8
```

Comment: An alternative which looks slightly neater is `{echo a=6; echo b=7; echo c=8 } >test.dat`

Comment: or, a single printf command: `printf %s=%s\n" a 6 b 7 c 8 > test.dat`

Comment: @NormanGray, you need a space following the open brace, and the last echo command must end with a semicolon -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping.

Comment: @glennjackman good point. I tested it with `zsh` -- bash and sh are clearly fussier.

Comment: @Igor, Ok I opened the fiel test.dat and read the variables I wanted to, but after that can I close this test.dat file and return back to the script file, and resume the remaining session of current script file. Or there is no need of it.

Comment: @IgorChubin what's the syntax of it?

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh: Of what exactly?

Comment: @IgorChubin After reading variables from test.dat how can I close this test.dat file and return back to the script file, and resume the remaining session of current script file.
Is there any syntax or command for this ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh: The file will be automatically closed and the execution flow goes on

Answer (score 1):

For reading the variables in the second script, you simply need to source it (import it):

```
## Put this line in your second script
. test.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of writing the file, there are different approaches.  Which is *better* depends on many factors.  One common approach is to use a heredoc:

```
cat > test.dat << EOF
a=6
b=7
c=8
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always a chance for modification, the method for writing your variable file is good. You can still change that as follows:

> echo -e "a=6\nb=7\nc=8" > test.dat

And to read the variable file by your script, you can add following:

> source test.dat

or

(My recommendation :-))

> . test.dat